# Range/Selection get HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uddaa/

Currently what it does, is when you click on the text, it will make an alert with the text up to that point. What can I do to get the html up to that point instead of just the text?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".content").on("click", function () {
    getBefore();
});

function getBefore() {
    var sel = document.getSelection();
    var off = sel.anchorOffset;
    var ran = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    ran.setStart($(".content").get(0), 0);
    alert(ran.toString());
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <p><b>Click</b> anywhere <u>within <em>the</em> text</u> to to see the code up to that point.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it specifically has this feature, but [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) is the best selection library I know of. It's worth a look.

Comment: From my understanding, Rangy only works on textareas and input fields. Am I incorrect about that?

Comment: No, it works on anything which can be selected within the DOM. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ran.cloneContents().childNodes[1].innerHTML` gives you the complete html.

See [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/MQpvF/) or the code snippet.

```js
document.querySelector(".content").addEventListener("click", getHtmlBeforeThis);

function getHtmlBeforeThis(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target.closest(".content");
  if (origin) {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    const offset = selection.anchorOffset;
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.setStart(origin, 0);
    const upToClickedHtml = range.cloneContents().childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    range.setEnd(origin, 0);
    console.clear();
    console.log(upToClickedHtml);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p><b>Click</b> anywhere <u>within <em>the</em> text</u> to to see the code up to that point.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library to do this:

```
rangy.getSelection().toHtml()
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/y857B/1/)

Comment: That gives me a blank alert box.

Comment: I think that may be because clicking the selection clears it before it's read. Try my updated fiddle where the selection is read by clicking a button.

Comment: It does work. The reason @GetOffMyLawn gets a blank alert box is that she doesn’t select anything before clicking “Get selection”.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSelectedHtml() {
    const selectionDiv = document.createElement("div");
    selectionDiv.appendChild(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
    return selectionDiv.innerHTML;
}
```